# Why is Terminal.app weird about stealing keyboard focus on Monterey?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, shortcut, keybindings

I use [Due](https://www.dueapp.com/) for reminders, and have it set up to use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to activate the Due window (which lives only in the Menu Bar, not the Dock). This works fine in most applications and on Big Sur it worked fine everywhere, but after a clean install of Monterey it seems that Terminal.app is at least partially eating this shortrcut.

If I do the following with Due initially deactivated:

1. <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to Chrome or TextMate or anything else.
2. Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> repeatedly.

then the Due window will come and go as expected, getting keyboard focus each time. But if I do the same with Terminal.app in step (1) then the Due window shows up after the first <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, but without keyboard focus, and will not disappear again later. It never becomes the active window.

In fact, the symptom is even more general. If Terminal.app is active and I use Spotlight to open System Preferences, System Preferences opens *behind* Terminal.app, without keyboard focus. No other app causes this symptom.

How do I get Apple Terminal or Iterm to not interfere with Due starting from the keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out this was due to the [Secure Keyboard Entry](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/47749/95778) setting in the Terminal menu:

[image: Terminal menu showing "Secure Keyboard Entry" checked]

Turning that off fixes the problem.

Comment: This was the same case for me when using iTerm