# How to switch foreground app / focus while using Terminal with "Secure Keyboard Entry"?

Tags: terminal, security

I am running Terminal with "Secure Keyboard Entry" enabled. This is on a MDM / managed computer where I cannot disable this option.

[It's been documented](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/431083/) that the "Secure Keyboard Entry" option stops `open <some app/file>` from "switching" apps (i.e. changing the foreground app). [Also see this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/439347/). [And this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/431083/).

i.e. when I type `open .` (to open the current folder in the Finder) or if I try to launch sublime using its CLI `subl` tool, opening/launching happens but in the background. The Terminal stays in the foreground.

Is there any way to issue a command in the Terminal with the "Secure Keyboard Entry" option enabled and to switch the foreground app?